# getting values using php simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to traverse through the images node in the xml at the bottom, but my code only displays the first image amongst many. I'm traversing through it using foreach, any help would be much appreciated.

Also, I'm trying to access the 'description' and 'features' under product, but I can't figure out how to access these.

```
    <?php 
    $mypix = simplexml_load_file('abc.xml');
    foreach ($mypix->package as $pixinfo):
        $title=$pixinfo->productTitle;
        $link=$pixinfo->url;
        $image=$pixinfo->imageUrl;    
        echo "<a href=\"",$link,"\"><img src=\"",$image,"\" alt=\"",$title,"\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\" /></a>\n";
        foreach ($pixinfo->images as $piximages):
            echo "<img src=\"",$piximages->image,"\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" />\n";
        endforeach;
        echo "<br />";
    endforeach;
?>


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<packages xmlns="http://www.google.com">
    <package>
        <productTitle>Product A</productTitle>
        <url>http://google.com</url>
        <imageUrl>h658279.jpg</imageUrl>
        <images>
            <image>658279.jpg</image>
            <image>658280.jpg</image>
            <image>658283.jpg</image>
        </images>
        <products>
            <product>
                <description>Why choose product</description>
                <locationDescription>Ideally located</locationDescription>
                <features>Buttons 12</features>
            </product>
        </products>
    </package>
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once (Tested)...

```
<?php
$mypix = simplexml_load_file('abc.xml');
foreach ($mypix->package as $pixinfo):
    $title = $pixinfo->productTitle;
    $link = $pixinfo->url;
    $image = $pixinfo->imageUrl;
    echo "<a href=\"", $link, "\"><img src=\"", $image, "\" alt=\"", $title, "\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\" /></a>\n";
    foreach ($pixinfo->images->image as $img) {
        echo "<img src=\"". $img. "\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" />\n";
    }
    echo "<br />";
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be:

```
 foreach ($mypix->packages as $pixinfo): //packages not package
```